# EF Code First project organization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, ef-code-first, code-organization

I am having trouble getting started on my first attempt with EF and Code First mostly due to trying to find an efficent way to organize the project in Visual Studio. I wanted to try Code First so I pictured a set of class files in a separate project to describe the entites, like **MyApp.Models**. To build on that I imagine I need something like Fluent API to make sure the database is created the way I expect which is where I hit the first snag. I think the only way to do this is to define the context where EF generates the database. *So where should that code creating the context be defined*? In a separate project like **MyApp.DAL**? I'd also like to include Asp.Net Identity 2.0 which I believe is part of defining the context so that is included in that step. Next I assume I need to actually call the code so EF can generate the DB which requires at least a configuration setting for the connection string. Eventually I want an MVC app but maybe next is a console EXE like **MyApp.ConsoleTest**? Also I'd also like a Web API project which would serve the MVC app. I think those can be covered with something like **MyApp.WebAPI** and **MyApp.ClientWebMVC**. Perhaps later I could also create **MyApp.ClientWPF** which would leverage the work done with the Web API. Along the way I should also probably have something like **MyApp.Common** or **Shared.Common** to hold things like logging and error catching.

I think the first few steps around the entities and context are what trip me up the most. I want to try and organize the data part of the code so changes can be isolated from ruining too much in the client apps. Is there a good tutorial on project organization that addresses EF Code First that isn't overly complicated (ie Unity of Work)?

Comment: Examples actually abound. Look here for instance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/tutorial-series-updated-for-entity-framework-6-code-first-with-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: The problem with examples like that is they wrap everything into a single (web) project. The only separation is via folders. If I want to create a Contoso WPF application or Web API I would then reference the web project? The "models" and "DAL" folders are what trips me up. Nothing can really begin until the context is generated in the DAL. But wrapping the models into the same project as the DAL seems wrong, although practical.

Comment: That's what the Enity Framework is all about: creating the possibility to use your bussiness objects as persistence objects. If that is a good thing? A question of mine about this was shot down by the moderators. You can always map the entities to your bussiness objects and vice versa to adher to a clean separation of bussiness and data code.